# Recreate the radio button behavior in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have recreated the radio button behavior in Sandbox. 
When one button is active, all the other ones should be inactive.

Please find the link here :
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-chaplygin-xf8el?fontsize=14

For 3 buttons I have created 3 functions. Is there a way to optimize my code with 1 single function ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by using an Array:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function ButtonToggle() {
  const [happy, setHappy] = useState([false, false, false]);

  function handle(idx) {
    let set = [false, false, false];
    set[idx] = !happy[idx];
    setHappy(set);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {happy[0] ? "" : ""}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handle(0);
        }}
      >
        bouton1
      </button>
      {happy[1] ? "" : ""}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handle(1);
        }}
      >
        bouton2
      </button>
      {happy[2] ? "" : ""}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handle(2);
        }}
      >
        bouton3
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-haibt-73df1

Comment: Not bad thanks a lot! The only thing is that you are loosing the toggle on each button, going from true to false if the same button is clicked.

Comment: Hi @musikarts if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: I did but I have a low reputation so I'm not sure if it is displayed !

Comment: @musikarts Thanks! It is displayed.